# How to chunk updates to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to update a table in SQL Server by setting a FLAG column to 1 for all values since the beginning of the year:

```
TABLE
DATE        ID     FLAG   (more columns...)
2016/01/01  1      0      ...
2016/01/01  2      0      ...
2016/01/02  3      0      ...
2016/01/02  4      0      ...
(etc)
```

Problem is that this table contains hundreds of millions of records and I've been advised to chunk the updates 100,000 rows at a time to avoid blocking other processes.

I need to remember which rows I update because there are background processes which immediately flip the FLAG back to 0 once they're done processing it.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can do this?
Each day's worth of data has over a million records, so I can't simply loop using the DATE as a counter. I am thinking of using the ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the date column and the ID column are sequential you could do a simple loop. By this I mean that if there is a record `id=1 and date=2016-1-1` then record `id=2 date=2015-12-31` could not exist. If you are worried about locks/exceptions you should add a transaction in the `WHILE` block and commit or rollback on failure.

Change the `@batchSize` to whatever you feel is right after some experimentation.

```
DECLARE @currentId int, @maxId int, @batchSize int = 10000

SELECT @currentId = MIN(ID), @maxId = MAX(ID) FROM YOURTABLE WHERE DATE >= '2016-01-01'

WHILE @currentId < @maxId
BEGIN
    UPDATE YOURTABLE SET FLAG = 1 WHERE ID BETWEEN @currentId AND (@currentId + @batchSize)
    SET @currentId = @currentId + @batchSize
END
```

As this as the update will never flag the same record to 1 twice I do not see a need to track which records were touched unless you are going to manually stop the process partway through.

You should also ensure that the ID column has an index on it so the retrieval is fast in each update statement.

Comment: Will this process each update in a separate transaction? or will it block until the entire loop is finished?

Comment: @JinKim - as is each `UPDATE` statement execution in the loop is its own transaction. If you want to block until the whole thing is finished you can wrap it in a transaction but as I understood your original question this is what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Just as a point, If the WHILE loop crash for any reason (server crash or any other issues), you'll loose the track of updated records.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a simple question or maybe I'm missing something.

You can create a temp/permanent table to keep track of updated rows.

```
create tbl (Id int) -- or temp table based on your case
insert into tbl values (0)

declare @lastId int = (select Id from tbl)

;with cte as (
    select top 100000 
    from YourMainTable
    where Id > @lastId
    ORDER BY Id
)
update cte 
set Flag = 1

update tbl set Id = @lastId + 100000
```

You can do this process in a loop (except the table creation part)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tmp_table
(

    id int ,
    row_number int
)

insert into #tmp_table
(

    id,
    row_number
)

--logic to load records from base table
select
    bt.id,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by id ) as row_number
from
    dbo.bas_table bt
where
    --ur logic to limit the records

declare @batch_size int = 100000;
declare @start_row_number int,@end_row_number int;
select
    @start_row_number = min(row_number),
    @end_row_number = max(row_number)
from
    #tmp_table

while(@start_row_number < @end_row_number)
begin
    update top @batch_size
        bt
    set
        bt.flag = 1
    from
        dbo.base_table bt
        inner join #tmp_table tt on
            tt.Id = bt.Id
    where
        bt.row_number between @start_row_number and (@start_row_number + @batch_size)
    set @start_row_number = @start_row_number + @batch_size
end
```